# How can I prevent my switching power supply from sudden voltage increases?

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply

I'm currently using a 3kW AC/DC converter which gave 48VDC output(Switch mode power supply). The device is capable to deliver up to 62.5A current to the load.
My application is a cyclic movement driven by a motor. Due to high torque requirements, the motor draws up to 25A current from the converter. The movement completed within 1 second and after then it starts again for n-times.
When the cyclic movement is finished, the output voltage of the power supply increases up to 62VDC. Since the device has internal over-voltage protection it shuts down itself and I cannot continue to my application.
How can I overcome this problem? Is there any solution to prevent that sudden voltage increase?

Thank you all

Comment: Effectively, a really powerful zener diode that clamps the voltage and dissipates the excess energy.

Comment: **Maybe** some **extremely large value capacitors** across the 48 V DC could help. I say **maybe** because the AC-DC converter might not like so much capacitance at its output. You could also try to add a continuous load, of for example 5 A, on the 48 V by using a resistor (it will need to be 10 Ohm, 230 Watt!!!) or some 48 V lightbulbs (or multiple 12 V or 24 V lightbulbs in series). Then the AC-DC's load will not suddenly drop to 0 A but to 5 A and that might help limit the overvoltage spike.

Comment: In industry, this would be accomplished with a [braking resistor](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=braking+resistor&t=opera&ia=web).

Comment: Braking resistor or regenerative battery charger are two of the options (obviously, one implies battery operation)

Comment: Power supplies usually are only capable of *adding* voltage to the output. Electrical DC motor are also DC generators so they will add even more voltage during the slowdown, due to inertia and stuff. This is often referred as "pumping the power supply". As other already commented usually you switch in a *big* resistor during brake or reconvert the power away for further usage

Comment: Get a better power supply... The supply you are using has an incredibly poor transient response.

Comment: @Stiddily The SMPS is sourcing only,  it can't sink the extra generated energy - this is the problem. The transient response has nothing to do, here.